# Application Window Size only 2/3 screen size

Tags: windows-10

I've had my ASUS laptop with Windows 10 for a long time.  All of a sudden things acted differently. I can only get an application (such as Excel) window to expand to 2/3 the width of the actual screen. I must have changed something without knowing it.  I'm scared of messing things up so I don't just poke around randomly.

Comment: Update drivers? Check your event logs? Can you move things to the part of the screen the apps won't maximize to? Do all programs behave the same, or do some work differently or correctly? Also, something changed, so figuring that out is a good part of finding the solution.